# Can i set targetSDK lesser than buildToolsVersion & compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play-services, android-support-library

I have upgraded `google-play-services` to `15.0.0`, that uses `android.support:26.1.0`, so i am planning to upgrade `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to  version  `26`.

But there are some external libraries`(.aar libraries)` that requires `targetSdkVersion` to be set to version `25`.

So if i set   `compileSdkVersion` to `26` and `buildToolsVersion` to `"26.0.0"` and keep `targetSdk` to version `25`, then what will happen

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `targetSdkVersion` should be <= `compileSdkVersion`. As the [Android Framework Developer said in this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd), ideally to have a steady state this should be the relationship of the compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion:

```
minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= 
    targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion (latest SDK)
```

Hope this helps.